# Wait for latest values from dependent ajax streams in BaconJS?

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

I have 3 streams. (1) `gradingResult` and `contextId` are ajax requests that depend on `studentResponse`. (2) For each `studentResponse` value, I need to fire an event with the `studentResponse` value and the corresponding result from the other two streams.

This question is similar but different than  [Wait for latest values from dependent streams in BaconJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344788/wait-for-latest-values-from-dependent-streams-in-baconjs). One key difference is that I don't know which of `gradingResult` and `contextId` will return first.

A note about the code: the code is based on production code. I do not have access to `gradingResult` or `contextId`. All I know is that they're ajax requests that take inputs from `studentResponse`.

Some sample code with desired output:

```
function _fauxAjax(val) {
  return Bacon.fromBinder(function(sink) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        sink(val); 
        sink(new Bacon.End());
    }, Math.random()*1000);
    return function() {}
  });
}

var studentResponse = new Bacon.Bus();
var gradingResult = studentResponse.flatMap(_fauxAjax);
var contextId = studentResponse.flatMap(_fauxAjax);
```

Given this input:

```
studentResponse.push(1);
studentResponse.push(2);
studentResponse.push(3);
```

Desired output:

```
{studentResponse:1, gradingResult:1, contextId:1 }
{studentResponse:2, gradingResult:2, contextId:2 }
{studentResponse:3, gradingResult:3, contextId:3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define the two latter ajax requests as independent streams, I don't see a practical solution for making sure the values are related.

So, to make absolutely sure that you get the `gradingResult` and `contextId` responses that were triggered by the same `studentResponse` I'd say you have to do something like this:

```
studentResponse.flatMap(function(response) {
  return Bacon.combineTemplate({
    studentResponse: response,
    gradingResult: _fauxAjax(response),
    contextId: _fauxAjax(response)
  })
}).log()
```